# How do I delete an empty directory linking two directories?

Tags: windows, directory

I have a ton of large files inside a directory. As the directory is accessible by anyone with access to a certain pc, the directory looks somewhat like this:

main folder\DIR

However, today someone has somehow moved in a middle-link directory so now it looks like:

main folder\newDIR\DIR

It is crucial for file transfer that the original directory tree is maintained, and thus I need to get rid of the \newDIR\ link. How do I do this most efficiently?

Comment: If it's a file system that supports reparse points, such as NTFS or ReFS, you can create a junction to "DIR" in "main folder", i.e. "main folder\DIR" -> "main folder\newDIR\DIR". Use CMD's `mklink /j <name> <target_directory>`.

Comment: A junction is a mount point that closely approximates the behavior of a Unix mount point, including bind mounts. It is not equivalent to a Unix symlink, in case what you read online confuses this issue. A lot of misleading statements have been made about junctions. In this case it acts as a bind mount.

Comment: For example, when reparsing relative symlinks (e.g. if "DIR\symlink" -> "..\spam.txt" and expects to reference "main folder\spam.txt"), a junction acts like a regular directory, just like a Unix bind mount. This differs from a directory symbolic link, which is resolved to the target before evaluating a relative symlink (and thus would lead to the latter relative symlink referencing "main folder\newDir\spam.txt"). Also, a junction is limited to local devices and is always evaluated on the server side in UNC paths. Symlinks are evaluated on the client, per L2L, L2R, R2L, and R2R policy.